# What is the German equivalent of (Ed.)?

Tags: translation

What is the German equivalent of the English "(Ed.)" used in footnotes to indicate an editor's note? Yes, I have tried dict.leo.org and dict.cc and could not find anything.

Comment: Can you give a more concrete example, i.e. a full note? Depending on the context it could be "Anm." (for "Anmerkung"), e.g. "Anmerkung des Bearbeiters". "Editor" is usually translated as Herausgeber (Hrsg.)

Comment: I often see "Anm. der Red" when the editor of a journalistic outlet remarks something into a quotation or similar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most common are:

> Anm. d. Verf. / A.d.V. – Anmerkung des Verfassers (author's note)
>
> Anm. d. Üb. / A.d.Ü. – Anmerkung des Übersetzers (translator's note)
>
> Anm. d. Hrsg. / A.d.H. – Anmerkung des Herausgebers (publisher's note)

Comment: "Anm. d. Red. / A.d.R. - Anmerkung der Redaktion" should also be in this List